# Show div for only 20% of people that enter in my site

Tags: javascript

I would like to show a div for only 20% of the traffic of my site, so i made this logic:

```
var div = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1) > 20 ? true : false;
if (div)
  // don't show
else
  // show
```

But I don't think this is precise, is it?

Thank you.

Comment: depends how many visitors you have... if you have a lot is good enought

Comment: On average it would be accurate if you have enough vistors.

Comment: Peter is right. If you have lots of visitors you will get a distribution close to 20%. If not, you might get something a little off.

Comment: I have a lot of visitors, 300 - 500 per hour, but I'm curious now, what if I didn't had?

Comment: I wouldnt use client side logic for this but server side logic. You could literally increment a server side variable and every time it gets to 5 reset it and tell the client to show the div. Of course start with 1 in this case. If you need to be exact at least -> you could use ajax as well to get the counters value - if you run into multiple requests at once.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do.  Are you trying to do some A B testing?  Are you still going to be able to get telemetry if you do this client side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With all random-ness, there needs to be a large enough sample size for the normal distribution to show up. As you can see, the more visitors you get, the closer that function will be to `20%`.

```js
function visitors(n) {
  var visited = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    visited += (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1) > 20 ? 0 : 1;
  console.log("Out of " + n + " visitors, " + visited + " were shown the div. (" + visited / n * 100 + "%)");
}

[1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000].forEach(x => visitors(x));
```

As [Radmation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4488725/radmation) mentioned, however, using the server would give you much more close to `20%` for a smaller number of visitors.

> I wouldnt use client side logic for this but server side logic. You could literally increment a server side variable and every time it gets to 5 reset it and tell the client to show the div. Of course start with 1 in this case. If you need to be exact at least -> you could use ajax as well to get the counters value - if you run into multiple requests at once.